# Passing query params to SQL View in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles

I'm working on a project using GeoServer to serve a vector-tiles map to an OpenLayers client. I would like to make a custom SQL view in GS where I can pass the zoom-level attribute from the GET-requests made by the client, so I can filter the data that's being returned from the PostGIS database. I've noticed that on the GET-requests, the zoom-level is being passed through the `TILEMATRIX-attribute` as a key-value pair separated by a colon. I.e. `TILEMATRIX=utm32_dk:7`

Would it be possible to make an SQL View along the lines of:

```
SELECT id, name, geom
FROM roads
WHERE zoom_level = %utm32_dk%;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with out some client level coding. GeoServer does provide a [series of environment variables](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html#predefined-variables) including the `wms_scale_denominator` variable that may be what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but can I use the `wms_scale_denominator`-variable in my SQL View statement?

Comment: I don't know, have a try